# DJango Dependant Dropdown Showing Invalid Choices Error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I tried to create the dependant dropdown following the most famous tutorial for it : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html. Although I am still getting the invalid choice error. How am i supposed to correct it?